# AWS RDS access policy not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, rds

I have wrote one custom aws policy to give all access of specific RDS instance to user but it gives below **error:**

```
User: arn:aws:iam::*******:user/dev-testrds-access is not authorized to perform: rds:DescribeDBInstances (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: )
```

AWS policy :

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowRDSDescribe",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "rds:Describe*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:rds:ap-southeast-1:********db:test-db*"
    }
]
```

}

But when i mentioned **"Resource": "*"** it works. I dont know where i am wrong. I want to give access to specific instance not for all instace. can help on this

Comment: Why is there a `*` at the end of the resource, after `test-db`?

Comment: The format of a RDS ARN is `arn:aws:rds:region:account-id:db:db-instance-name`. Are you missing the colon between the account-id and `db`?